# I need to input the print from this function into a tkinter page

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this function that prints 25 lines of text and I need to input it in my tkinter page, but ever time it doesn't seem to work.

I've tried using text.input but it didn't seeem to work

This is the function I need to print:

```
def decode(secretmessage):
    for key in range(len(alphabet)):
        newAlp = alphabet[key:] + alphabet[:key]
        attempt = ""
        for i in range(len(message)):
            index = alphabet.find(message[i])
            if index < 0:
                attempt += message[i]
            else:
                attempt += newAlp[index]
        print("Key: " + str(key) + " - " + attempt)
        print()
```

This is what I tried:

```
def finalprint (uncoded):
    print("Key: " + str(key) + " - " + attempt)
    print()

text = Text.insert(root, finalprint(message), width=450, height=450)
```

It doesn't work to show up for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` command prints the given text to console. It does returns `None`

Your `finalprint` function also returns `None` while `Text.insert` expects a string as an input.

Instead of printing the output you can store the values into a string.

```py
def finalprint(uncoded): ## may need different inputs as key and attempts are not in scope
    string =  ""
    string = string + "Key: " + str(key) + " - " + attempts + "\n"
    return string
```

However the input to the finalprint function is uncoded while the variables used in it are key and attempts. You may need to pass in more information to the function for it to work like you have it written.